# Proof or Counterexample: A ($K_3$,$C_5$)-free graph has fractional chromatic number at most 7/3.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> **Claim.** A triangle-free simple undirected graph $G$ without an induced 5-cycle $C_5$ satisfies $\chi_f(G)\leq 7/3$, where $\chi_f(G)$ denotes the [fractional chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coloring).

The question is essentially whether one can do better than $\chi_f(C_7)=7/3$. I can't find a counterexample. The standard examples to make the fractional chromatic number explode are Kneser graphs and Mycielski graphs. The former don't satisfy the assumptions, and the latter seem to always introduce a $C_5$. I'm probably missing something here. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: For something close to the Mycielski approach, see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.1025).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are claiming that Kneser graphs don't work. However we know that if $G\cong K(n,k)$ then
$$\textrm{odd-girth}(G)=2\left\lceil\frac{k}{n-2k}\right\rceil+1,$$
and
$$\chi_f(G) = n/k.$$

(see Poljak and Tuza, *Maximum bipartite subgraphs of Kneser graphs* , Graphs Combin . , 3 (1987) ,
191 – 199 .)

The ceil function saves you here. I guess you got rid of it in your computation ?

> You need to find $n,k$ such that $n/k > 7/3$ and $2\left\lceil\frac{k}{n-2k}\right\rceil+1 \geq 7$, hence such that $$\frac{k}{n-2k}>2.$$ Therefore take $n,k$ such that $$7/3 < n/k < 5/2.$$

Answer (score 2):

A classic result of Erdős (1959), most commonly encountered between Chapters 3 and 4 of Alon and Spencer's *Probabilistic Method*, is the result:

> For all $k, l$ there exists a graph $G$ with $\operatorname{girth}(G)>l$ and $\chi(G) > k$.

This statement doesn't give us what we want, but the proof method does. I will summarize. For some $\theta < 1/l$, we sample a graph $G \sim G(n, p)$ with $p = n^{\theta-1}$, and show that with positive probability, it has independence number $\alpha(G) < 3n^{1-\theta}\ln n$ and at most $n/2$ cycles of length less than $l$. Deleting a vertex from each cycle leaves a graph $G^*$ with the desired girth and at least $n/2$ vertices, and we have $$\chi(G^*) \ge \frac{|V(G^*)|}{\alpha(G^*)} \ge \frac{n/2}{3n^{1-\theta}\ln n} = \frac{n^{\theta}}{6\ln n},$$ which can be made arbitrarily high.

When $\operatorname{girth}(G^*)>5$, $G^*$ is $\{K_3, C_5\}$-free, and the lower bound $\chi(G^*) \ge \frac{|V(G^*)|}{\alpha(G^*)}$ is also a lower bound on fractional chromatic number. Therefore in particular we can find a $\{K_3,C_5\}$-free graph with fractional chromatic number greater than $7/3$ (or greater than $100$).

---

*Note: an advantage of the random graph approach is that we can easily extend the result. A disadvantage is that it gives enormous graphs: if we do the math with $\theta=1/6$, we need more than $10^{16}$ vertices to guarantee $\chi_f(G^*) > \frac73$, and more than $10^{27}$ vertices to guarantee $\chi_f(G^*) > 100$.*